# disable "SSL 2.0+ upgrade support" in nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I evaluated the SSL credentials of my server with qualsys ssl page ( https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/index.html ) and found the entry "SSL 2.0+ upgrade support" being marked as yes. I want to disable this sslv2 handshake too. I searched around and found http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,104032m, which points to creating a openssl.cnf file.

Have a naive question here. After creating the file, does one need to re-key his certificate for this to work ? Are there any other steps to follow ?

I use nginx 1.0.11 and openssl "OpenSSL 1.0.0e-fips 6 Sep 2011". I have set ssl_ciphers in nginx to SSLv3 TLSv1;

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate will work. `openssl.cnf` usually already exist in the system, so you need to edit one. Its location depends on which distribution/server version you are using. For example, if you are using Linux/Debian, it is located in /etc/ssl. But if you compiled OpenSSL it from the sources, the location would be of `--sysconfdir` used in `configure` (usually, `--prefix` + /etc). Make changes to the file as suggested on forum and restart nginx.